# grep says 'invalid character range'

Tags: macos, bash, grep, find

So I'm using a combination of `find` and `grep` to filter out a list of file names from a plain text document.

Here's the command I run:

```
find /Volumes/Documents\ -\ Part\ 1/July 2009 -type f | grep -vf files.txt
```

In files.txt I have this:

```
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/vacation.pdf
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/pie time!.jpg
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/Coding/Unix/sample.sh
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/trip-to-spain.pages
```

I want it to output any non-matching lines, but instead I get this:

```
grep: invalid character range
```

What is the cause of this? There is a lot more to files.txt, I just omitted it because it would be too long. I do have several unicode characters in there, too. Could that be causing any issues?

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release, grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR; add `-F`

---

The `-f` option of grep is used to refer to a file that contains a list of **patterns** - your file does not contain a list of patterns it contains a list of filenames

man grep

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>                 Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.   The  empty file
>                 contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.   (-f  is
>                 specified by POSIX.)

You need to make sure any metacharacters in your filenames are escaped unless you want them to be treated as metacharacters.

---

```
$ cat files.txt
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/vacation.pdf
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/pie time!.jpg
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/Coding/Unix/sample.sh
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/trip-to-spain.pages

$ echo a | grep -vf files.txt
a
```

It seems to me your files.txt probably contains more than the four lines you show.

Check the file using

```
$ wc files.txt
  4  21 221 files.txt

$ sum files.txt
43924     1
```

---

If in doubt, use the `-F` option (uppercase F) - but then you don't escape metacharacters in file.txt.

Note the following

```
$ cat files.txt
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/vacation.pdf
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/pie time!.jpg
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/Coding/Unix/sample.sh
/Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/trip-to-spain.pages
[z-a]

$ echo aaa | grep -vf files.txt
grep: Invalid range end

$ echo aaa | grep -Fvf files.txt
aaa
```

The `-F` option tells grep that your search patterns contain no regular expressions and that it should treat them as plain text.

Comment: Escaped in files.txt? I just did now and I get the same error...

Comment: I get `2715   28337  296565 files.txt` and `62495 290 files.txt` for `wc` and `sum` respectively

Comment: See amended answer, `-F` option should help. @leetbacoon

Comment: Works lovely, thank you! I'd up vote it if I could, but my rep isn't high enough.