# grep -Ef saying 'invalid character range'. Again

Tags: macos, bash, unix, grep

This is a followup to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1309388/grep-says-invalid-character-range). The differences are listed below.

Here's an excerpt of what's inside foo.txt (it's gigantic):

```
^.{64}  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/Mum & Dad/Winter Wonderland [日本].mkv$
^.{64}  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/March 2004/Mac OS X/Adobe Illustrator Documents/swimming.zip$
```

And here's an excerpt of what's inside bar.txt (also gigantic):

```
c815bebbc553fdf13b16bc99d417053cbe22c13c714d12cf16e740516a5cdeda  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/Mum & Dad/Winter Wonderland [日本].mkv
cab951c9779db6d484cec544482e742c75effea61c426264cb47788fddd4999e  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/March 2004/Baseball/Pro Yakyuu.7z
635431114b7d898cfebd78f25b50bfea1f1593c292c15e631377347abba3e0e6  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/March 2004/Mac OS X/Adobe Illustrator Documents/swimming.zip
```

And here's the command I run:

```
grep -Ef foo.txt bar.txt
```

`grep` spits out this:

```
grep: invalid character range
```

Instead, I'd like `grep` to output this:

```
c815bebbc553fdf13b16bc99d417053cbe22c13c714d12cf16e740516a5cdeda  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/July 2009/Mum & Dad/Winter Wonderland [日本].mkv
635431114b7d898cfebd78f25b50bfea1f1593c292c15e631377347abba3e0e6  /Volumes/Documents - Part 1/March 2004/Mac OS X/Adobe Illustrator Documents/swimming.zip
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I have change in order for `grep` to output what I need it to?

Mac OS X Yosemite, bash 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: Does foo.txt contain square brackets somewhere?

Comment: @choroba Yes, it does. And it contains a lot of unicode characters as well, like `日本`

Comment: Do you want `grep` to interpret the strings in square brackets as character classes? If so, you need to make sure than ranges never list the characters in wrong order. If not, backslash the square brackets.

Comment: @choroba I want `grep` to interpret them as literal characters. So, make brackets look like `\[` and `\]` inside of both foo.txt and bar.txt?

Comment: I'm hoping there's a more efficient solution. Some of my files have `\[` and `\]` in their names. And I'm not certain, but it looks like it didn't output any lines containing brackets (yes, I escaped them).

Comment: No escaping in bar.txt.

Comment: Solved. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49603277/special-characters-and-literal-characters-in-a-text-file-in-grep/49609047#49609047).

Answer (score 0):

I am inferring from the comments to the OP that you want the bracket characters "[" and "]" in foo.txt to match the corresponding literal bracket characters in bar.txt.  Assuming that is correct, they need to be backslash-escaped in foo.txt (only).

One way to make this modification en masse is with `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/\[/\\[/g' -e 's/\]/\\]/g' foo.txt
```

That will leave you with a modified foo.txt, and the original file as foo.txt.bak.

If my inferences are not correct, please edit your post to include specific lines that don't work for you.  The lines you post above do grep correctly for me, once this sed command is applied to foo.txt.